# Efficient sampling from a multivariate Gaussian Mixture distribution for a given CDF level

Tags: sampling, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have a multivariate Gaussian Mixture (GM) distribution. I am wondering if there is any more efficient way of drawing samples (i.e., identify the iso-surface) from a multivariate Gaussian Mixture distribution for a given joint CDF (joint cumulative distribution function) level?

Here is my current solution (a brutal one). I'm generating a large number of realizations from the GM distribution and evaluate the corresponding CDF value of each of the realizations. Then I select those that are closest to the target CDF value. But this method can be quite time consuming because the large number of CDF evaluations.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't understand what you are after,  What is "the target CDF" value?  Are  you trying to calculate or estimate values of the joint cdf of a GM distribution?

Comment: @kimchilover I mean I hope to generate sample realizations whose CDF values are the same as a prescribed CDF level. This is basically an inverse CDF problem, but I couldn't find any solution for multivariate normal or multivariate Gaussian mixture distribution.

Comment: Still not clear to me.  What would you do (or want to do) if the "mixture" was a single pure bivariate gaussian?  Pick a point on the locus $F(x,y)=c$ where $F$ is the CDF of the gaussian?

Comment: @kimchilover Yes, that is exactly what I wanted. I wanted to know if there are any more efficient methods instead of direct Monte-Carlo sampling.